# How to compute the instants of switching of a function

Tags: matlab, counting, evaluation

Given the minimum time control problem solved by `u` being the 'switching curve'

```
g=1;
b=1;
w=1;
tf=10;
x0=[0;0]
t_interval=[0, tf];
[t,x]=ode45(@(t,x) dynamics(t,x,b,g,w),t_interval,x0);

function dx = dynamics(t,x,b,g,w);
u=-signum(x(2)+(1+g)*x(1)+g*b/2*x(1)*abs(x(1)));
dx=[x(2);-w^2*x(1)-2*g*x(2)+u/b];
end
```

I would like compute the instants of time `t` in which `u=-signum(x(2)+(1+g)*x(1)+g*b/2*x(1)*abs(x(1)))` changes sign.

I tried with a counting function but it doesn't work with `ode45`.
EDIT : I solved the problem with ode45 but clearly this strategy is not ideal since returns like 12k number of change which is clearly wrong. Here's the code :

sign_changes = 0;
for i = 2:length(t)
if (x(i, 2) + (1+g)*x(i, 1) + g*b/2*x(i, 1)*abs(x(i, 1))) * (x(i-1, 2) + (1+g)*x(i-1, 1) + g*b/2*x(i-1, 1)*abs(x(i-1, 1))) < 0
sign_changes = sign_changes + 1;
end
end

From the attached plot, it's clear that there are only two switches.
[image]

Comment: What does “it doesn’t work” mean? Did you get an error message? A wrong result? No result?

Comment: yes, i get an error

Comment: Then please copy-paste the full error message into your post, including the stack trace.